# Is it correct to say "full of protein" instead of "high in protein"?

Tags: word-choice

Is it somehow acceptable to say "this food/dish/product is full of protein"? saying that I am aware that the right and formal choice will be "high in protein".

Comment: *Syntactically* it's fine. You can nit-pick about the *semantics*, but as this usage chart for [***foods** {which are} **full of sugar***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=foods+are+full+of+sugar&year_start=1970&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows, the construction is quite common.

Comment: thank you for a quick answer)

Comment: I'm only giving you *my* opinion - I can see why you *might* think it's "sub-standard", but I have no problem with it. Others may have different opinions, and it's possible they think it's at least "informal", even if it's not outright "wrong". I don't actually agree, but I'm not gonna try to talk you out of your stated position that *the right and formal choice will be "high in protein"*.

Comment: even more thank you for such a nicely detailed answer)

Comment: Fine grammatically, but factually it's probably inaccurate because "full of" suggests 100% or near, whereas even a high-protein food like lean meat is maybe only 30% protein. That said, "full of" is often used casually and inaccurately. (You should explain in the Q why you think "full of" is wrong; saying that "high in" is right doesn't explain that.)

Comment: thank you  a lot, it was helpful

Comment: @StuartF: Yeah - *This bucket is full of water* and *Egg whites are full of protein* might be *almost* literally true, but mostly, *...full of protein / fat / sugar / salt . ...* is exaggeration for effect.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's completely normal in everyday speech, even if it isn't the most technical sounding. It's common, for example, to say foods are "*full of goodness*", "*packed with vitamins*" or "*loaded with sugar*". Simply put, '*full of*' is an all-purpose phrase for saying something contains a lot of a particular thing.

Comment: thank you for such a clear explanation

Comment: When I and my friends were particularly energetic as kids, the adults would say we were 'full of beans'.

Comment: In my early teens, yogurt began to be promoted as a mass-market product, rather than something for bearded, sandal-wearing health-nut weirdos. One product was Ski yogurt - _Ski, the full-of-fitness food!_ (sung in the TV ads).

Comment: Thank you very much